# dropzonejs multifile upload not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am trying to use the multi upload but in my **MVC** action I am not getting a list of uploaded files, instead I am getting file[] for each uploaded item.

I am uploading 2 files, but when I access this in my controller via:

```
        foreach (string filename in Request.Files)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[filename];
            //file.name always reads from file[] and picks the first file in all requests


        }
```

My full request is:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:54434/1328/uploads/new
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:8957136
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG
Cookie:glimpsePolicy=On; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1; glimpseId=Chrome 28.0; __RequestVerificationToken=itQ6HqqB_D7H_Y924w-HFfF8tq
ASP.NET_SessionId=cnj4lzpunuxnbyunl1m5gtpn
Glimpse-Parent-RequestID:04a1b6d2-6c6a-4da0-936d-3ff39e5b8c6c
Host:localhost:54434
Origin:http://localhost:54434
Referer:http://localhost:54434/1328/uploads/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"

dmPL-YRqsiwjKy43rlkYIBJE4kPlthsyL0IgnyHbtrD7Doczpbu9Z1SYeoL_93vuR15-6HfpNCCEzkzLYHBIxFJOQd3ynRGGYqILGpMWdLE1
------WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="private_upload"

true
------WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3


------WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="Sleep Away.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mp3


------WebKitFormBoundarysX8tBB9TH4BzWZsG--
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 16 Aug 2013 10:55:23 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcU3VydmVudHJpeFxhcHBcU3VydmVudHJpeFxGYXN0U3VydmV5b3JzXDEzMjhcdXBsb2Fkc1xuZXc=?=
```

````

Dropzone config is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#my-awesome-dropzone", {
            paramName: "files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            forceFallback: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFilesize: 10,
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            clickable: ".dropzone" //make only this region clickable
        });

        myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
            console.debug("added a file: " + file.name);
        });

        myDropzone.on("success", function (file) {
            $("#drop-success").show();
        });

        $("#btnDropzone").click(function () {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### How can I get each uploaded file in my controller so I can process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following solution is valid for dropzone 3.7.3.*

To fix this, change this line in dropzone.js:

```
formData.append("" + this.options.paramName + (this.options.uploadMultiple ? "[]" : ""), file, file.name);
```

to

```
formData.append("" + this.options.paramName + (this.options.uploadMultiple ? "[" + _l + "]" : ""), file, file.name);
```

Don't forget to include this non-minified version.

I'll try to suggest this patch to Enyo, on github.

Comment: if your PR is accepted, please can you update your comment and I will accept it. (useful for anyone else who wants this to work) :)

Comment: I can't do coffeescript either! But @Enyo will fix it in the next release :)

Answer (score 1):

If the input name `file[]` is actually the problem, then you can set the Dropzone option `uploadMultiple` to false. This will create multiple requests and send every file on it's own instead of sending all parallel uploaded files in one request.

Comment: exactly what I did, but I wanted to create multiple uploads hence I am trying to get this to work.

Comment: If you would create multiple input fields in a form and you wanted them to be uploaded as an array, how would this work in asp.net? Is it valid to use multiple input fields with the `name="files[]"` attribute? Or do they need to have indexes like `name="files[1]"`?

Comment: they *must* have indexes, else they are not read at all. The way I am reading the file is using the framework Request.Files, you *can* create model binders to get this to work but i feel an index is a simpler option as it will just work. I don't think that will break other frameworks at all, sounds logical to me...

Comment: I would have made a PR on github (I am hahmed) but I dont really know coffee script :P

Comment: AFAIK This needs updating: formData.append "#{@options.paramName}#{if @options.uploadMultiple then "[]" else ""}", file, file.name for file in files

Comment: It's going to be in the next release: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/424

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute  enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form

**--edit**

you need to add this option

parallelUploads: 10 
Only the number of files which is specified in the parallelUploads option will be uploaded. The standard value of parallelUploads seems to be 2.

this is not a good solution as you don't know how many files to be uploaded

so i have edit the

```
  $("#btnDropzone").click(function () {

        var fileCount = myDropzone.files.length;
        alert(fileCount);
        alert(fileCount % myDropzone.options.parallelUploads);
        var loopsCount = fileCount / myDropzone.options.parallelUploads;

        if (fileCount % myDropzone.options.parallelUploads != 0) {
            loopsCount = loopsCount + 1;
        }

        alert(loopsCount);
        for (var i = 0; i < loopsCount ; i++) {
            alert(i);
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        }


    });
```

Comment: I got a feeling its related to .net I think its because file[] is being passed in for all uploads, it rather should be something like file[0], file[1] or even file[filename]

Comment: don't think so,
as if you add option  "parallelUploads: 10" to drop zone options it will pass 10 file and if its value is 3  it will pass 3 files
this option has a default value of 2

Comment: Using dropzone doesn't require a <form> and neither the OP mentioned one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I replaced the mvc action for

```
        for (int arquivo = 0; arquivo < Request.Files.Count; arquivo++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[arquivo];

            //...

        }
```

And now it works fine.